# Starbound Matter Manipulator Upgrades not working

Tags: starbound

I have recently started a new playthrough on Starbound. I have gathered a few manipulator modules to upgrade my manipulator, but it's not allowing me to upgrade.

Say I want to upgrade to get the ability to pick up water, I simply go into the manipulator upgrade GUI and select the water icon, then click upgrade.

The problem I'm currently having with this is, while I get the upgrade, nothing unlocks and the GUI doesn't register the fact that I have the new upgrade. I can pick up liquids fine, but the GUI still allows me to "upgrade" my manipulator to get the liquid upgrade. It the upgrade button will be available and it will consume my modules, but will not unlock anything else. This is the case with any upgrade I try it on.

Since, from my searches, I have found that the race matters so my race is the [Felin race](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=729429063)

Comment: Since you're obviously using mods - what mods are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's provbalby a bug due to your race mod. Try with one of the Base game races. It wouldn't surprise me that your mod mess with the GUI of your game.